# Can I annotate a pdf without anyone knowing?

Tags: pdf, preview

I had to edit something on a pdf (I added a white rectangle somewhere).
The pdf looks totally fine but if someone opens it he can see the annotations with the inspector.

I exported the pdf as a (new) pdf, but if I double click anywhere on the pdf  it is pretty clear I added rectangles.

Is there a way to make it look like I never added anything?
Thanks

On this screenshot (a part of the document) I double clicked outside of annotations. The white rectangle will show clearly
[image: example]

Comment: did you try to print it as PDF ? but then not actually print but save instead.

Comment: @Buscar웃 yes, that's what I did and that's what the white/blue zones are in the screenshot. I think the white zones that I added are not the same white as the scan (although looks the same with our eyes) but double clicking on them will show them, so if the receiver double clicks here and there on the pdf he will know

Comment: how did you make annotations, in Adobe or Preview or ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 in Preview